# How to replace elements if two booleans are true in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
Y_Pred[Y_Pred < 0.99 and Y_Pred > 0.98] = 1
Y_Pred[Y_Pred <=0.98 or Y_Pred >= 0.99] = 0
```

But the `and` and the `or` aren't correct?

Answer (score 4):

You should use bitwise operations `|` and `&` instead of `and` and `or`. Also, you can use `np.where` like this:

```
Y_Pred = np.where((Y_Pred < 0.99) & (Y_Pred > 0.98),1,0)
```

or just:

```
Y_Pred = ((Y_Pred < 0.99) & (Y_Pred > 0.98)).astype(int)
```

Comment: Its a pandas dataframe, but using the np.where works on it... why is that?

Comment: Most of the time a dataframe/series can behave as a 2D/1D numpy array. Pandas is designed so that DataFrame/Series is downcast to respective numpy array when called by numpy functions. Depeding on the situation, you may get a DataFrame/Series or just a numpy array back.